# log line numbers of executed java code...won't this slow down the execution?

Tags: java, code-coverage

I have referred this link and my question is based on it. 
[Log line numbers of executed java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853747/log-line-numbers-of-executed-java-code)

I was very happy with Edwin Buck's answer. My doubt is that wont checking the code line by line make it slow. Can we do the code coverage block by block or rather method by method and give an approximate estimate of the line numbers in each block? Is this possible and if yes what would be a good approach?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using code coverage tools is a little slower than normal execution.  The simple solution is to run the code less often. Instead of looping one million times, loop 100,000 times instead.  For code which is only executed a few times, it won't make any difference.